# Guitar getting out of tune quickly

Tags: guitar, tuning

I have a Procraft guitar (made in China) that gets out of tune very quickly - especially after 2-3 minutes of strumming.  Specifically, the 4th and 5th strings get out of tune more than the other strings.

I noticed the bridge of the guitar has come up a bit. I have glued it, and have kept the guitar detuned for 24 hours.  Hopefully, this will solve the issue.

If this does not solve the issue, do I need to change the strings?  The bridge?  Something else?

Answer (score 5):

Cheap strings also do not keep their tune as well as the better quality ones, meaning this relates to tensile strength and elasticity of the materials used.

On new strings, one solution is to up tight them some amount and leave overnight, and then tune-down instead of tune up. On Cheaper strings more than one consecutive night may be needed.

Also, if you reglued the bridge, depending on the glue used, and how you clamped it, 24 hours of drying time may not be enough. You should use carpenter glue for guitar, white one, would say, and clean and rough up the joint areas a little so glue absorbs into the wood. Clamping is very important to force the glue into the wood fibers, but not to be overdone.

Comment: I wouldn't try the trick of over-tuning on a cheap guitar, it might not bear up to the extra strain. But otherwise agree. +1 Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

If the bridge was coming up then that was probably the problem, so check to see if your fix has sorted it out.

The other likely causes of getting out of tune on cheap guitars:

- machine heads slipping (can be fixed with a locking nut)
- nut sticking (rub graphite in the grooves)